# How do I group columns with many relationships like this?

Tags: mysql, join

It's been a long time since I posted last (I have a killer headache today) so if this question gets butchered, I'll understand.

I'm joining multiple tables to get data that looks like this (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables there really isn't a table view on StackOverflow?)

```
| course_name    | student_name  |  credit_type  | 
| course_1       | student_1     |  credit_2     |
| course_1       | student_1     |  credit_3     |
| course_1       | student_1     |  credit_4     |
| course_1       | student_2     |  credit_1     |
| course_1       | student_2     |  credit_2     |
| course_1       | student_2     |  credit_3     |
| course_1       | student_2     |  credit_4     |
| course_1       | student_3     |  credit_1     |
| course_1       | student_3     |  credit_2     |
| course_1       | student_3     |  credit_3     |
| course_1       | student_3     |  credit_4     |
| course_2       | student_1     |  credit_1     |
| course_2       | student_1     |  credit_2     |
| course_2       | student_1     |  credit_3     |
| course_2       | student_1     |  credit_4     |
| course_2       | student_2     |  credit_1     |
| course_2       | student_2     |  credit_2     |
| course_2       | student_2     |  credit_3     |
| course_2       | student_2     |  credit_4     |
| course_2       | student_3     |  credit_1     |
| course_2       | student_3     |  credit_2     |
| course_2       | student_3     |  credit_3     |
...........
```

I want data that groups all the students credits per student, so it to look like this

```
| course_name  |    student_name  | credit_type                              |
| course_1     |    student_1     | credit_2, credit_3, credit_4             |
| course_1     |    student_2     | credit_1, credit_2, credit_3, credit_4   |
| course_1     |    student_3     | credit_1, credit_3, credit_4             |
| course_2     |    student_1     | credit_1, credit_2, credit_4             |
| course_2     |    student_2     | credit_1, credit_2, credit_4             |
| course_2     |    student_3     | credit_1, credit_2, credit_4             |
| ............ |    ..............| ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., .|
```

I'm aware of GROUP_CONCAT, I'm just not sure how to implement it in this case.
Keep in mind this is a legacy system that is being put down for good soon.

What's the most straightforward way to do this?

If you can help me I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to `GROUP BY` on two columns (`course_name, student_name`) here:

```
SELECT
  course_name, 
  student_name, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(credit_type)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY course_name, student_name
```